# $P(V_1<V_2^2)$ given the fact they are IID

Tags: probability, statistics

[image]

Not really understanding the last line when they convert the probability to (v^2)^5. Really no idea where they're getting that. Am I missing some information? Thanks!

Comment: You're given the pdf $f(v)$. To get $P(V_1<v)$, you want the cdf $F(v)$. Now, do you know how to get the cdf from the pdf?

Comment: You'd integrate the pdf to get the cdf, which I'm not totally seeing how becomes v^10

Comment: It doesn't become $v^{10}$. The cdf is $F(v)=v^5$. But you want $P(V_1<\color{red}{v^2})$, which is $F(\color{red}{v^2})=(v^2)^5$.

Comment: ohhhhhh. Wow that makes total sense. Thanks!

Comment: For archive: $\mathsf{Beta}(5,1).$